# How to set column value true for one package when three packages are created with laravel factory?

Tags: php, laravel, factory, faker

I'm currently working in a project and I want to generate fake data in packages table.

I've a boolean column `featured` to set package featured or not. While generating fake data I want just one featured package every three package row.

Here is my code,

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

use App\Paragliding\Models\Package\Package;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

$factory->define(Package::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->text(15),
        'created_by' => App\User::where('role_id',3)->first()->id,
        'feature_image' => function()  use($faker){
            $name = $faker->text(10);
            Image::canvas(1024,768,$faker->hexcolor())->save(config('image.package_feature_path').$name.'jpg');
            return $name.'jpg';
        },
        'images' => function() use($faker){
            $images = array();
            for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
                $name = $faker->text(10);
                Image::canvas(1024,768,$faker->hexcolor())->save(config('image.package_gallery_path').$name.'jpg');
                $images[] = $name.'jpg';
            }
            return json_encode($images);
        },
        'description' => $faker->realText(150),
        'featured' => $faker->randomElement([0,1]),

    ];
});
```

Is it possible with the factory ?

Any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can set fields when creating models via a factory. In your seeder:

```
factory(Package::class)->create([
  'featured' => true
]);
```

should create one Package with the `featured` field set to true. Any other values will be taken from your above factory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, What I want is if we create 30 package then 10 featured and 20 unfeatured. can we acheive that ?

Comment: You can tell your seeder to create 20 unfeatured Packages by just using `factory(Package::class, 20)->create();` (will take your defaults set in factory) and `factory(Package::class, 10)->create('featured' => true);` to create 10 featured Packages. More on Seeders at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/seeding

Comment: Thanks I will see